# Text-decoration: none not working

Tags: css, html, text-decorations

Totally baffled! I've tried rewriting the `text-decoration: none` line several different ways. I also managed to re-size the text by targeting it but the `text-decoration: none` code will not take.

Help much appreciated.

Code

```css
.widget    
{
     height: 320px;
     width: 220px;
     background-color: #e6e6e6;
     position: relative;                              
     overflow: hidden;                          
}


.title    
{
     font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif;
     font-size: 12px;
     color: #E6E6E6;
     text-align: center;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     background-color: #4D4D4D;    
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     padding: 5px;
     width: 100%;
     margin-bottom: 1px;
     height: 28px;
     text-decoration: none;
}

a .title    
{
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
    <div class="widget">  
        <div class="title">Underlined. Why?</div>  
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: I'm with Nikola, no underlines. Also, when posting a demo please consider tidying your white-space; the goal is to have a demo we can work with, see and read, easily. Further, a `div` nested within an `a` element is invalid outside of HTML5, so be sure of your doctypes when using that construction.

Comment: I'm not seeing any underline.

Comment: I'm using Safari 5.1.7. That's really odd.

Comment: It isn't underlined for me, but your HTML has some semantic issues.

Comment: It's underlined in IE7 and IE6, per my tests.

Comment: @OllyF I am using the same browser. Let me know if my answer works for you.

Comment: In which browser??, in my FF see the text whitout decorations

Comment: See my (and Woz)'s answers below.  Alternatively you can move the <a> tag INSIDE the div tags with the id "widget" and it should work.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You have a block element (div) inside an inline element (a). This works in HTML 5, but not HTML 4. Thus also only browsers that actually support HTML 5.

When browsers encounter invalid markup, they will try to fix it, but different browsers will do that in different ways, so the result varies. Some browsers will move the block element outside the inline element, some will ignore it.

Answer (score 58):

```
a:link{
  text-decoration: none!important;
}
```

=> Working with me :) , good luck

Comment: very cool, thanks! And btw, when I need to underline for hover, the same solution worked - 
**.some_title:hover
{ text-decoration: underline!important; }**

Comment: That simply works!

Answer (score 14):

Use [CSS Pseudo-classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) and give your  tag a class, for example:

```
<a class="noDecoration" href="#">
```

and add this to your stylesheet:

```
.noDecoration, a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Add this statement on your header tag:

```
<style>
a:link{
  text-decoration: none!important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try placing your `text-decoration: none;` on your a:hover css.

Answer (score 3):

if you want a nav bar do

```
ul{ list-style-type: none; } li{text-decoration: none;
```

- This will make it want to make the style of the list type to None or nothing

with the < a > tag:

```
a:link {text-decoration: none}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have an answer:

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="widget">  
        <div class="title" style="text-decoration: none;">Underlined. Why?</div>  
    </div>
</a>​
```

It works.

Answer (score 2):

Add a specific class for all the links :

html :

```
<a class="class1 class2 noDecoration"> text </a>
```

in css :

```
.noDecoration {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no underline even I deleted 'text-decoration: none;' from your code.
But I had a similar experience.

Then I added a Code

```
a{
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

and

```
a:hover{
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

So, try your code with :hover.

Answer (score 1):

As a sidenote, have in mind that in other cases a codebase might use a `border-bottom` css attribute, for example `border-bottom: 1px;`, that creates an effect very similar to the `text-decoration: underline`. In that case make sure that you set it to none, `border-bottom: none;`

Answer (score 0):

I had lots of headache when I tried to customize a WordPress theme and the text-decoration didn't help me.
In my case I had to remove the box-shadow as well.

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An old question and still no explanation. The underline is drawn not on your `<div class="title">` element but on its parent `a`, since all browsers set this style for links by default. 
 
If you provide custom decoration style for the inner `div` - it will be visible instead of the parent style. But if you set none (and it is already set on divs by default), your `div` **will not be decorated**, but its **parent decoration will become visible** instead. 
So, as people suggested, in this case to remove all the decoration `text-decoration: none;` should be set on the parent `a` element.