# Text-decoration: none; not working

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am posting here for the first time. I am doing one project for an online web development course, I have created a footer using the footer tag and I'm using Bootstrap CSS file and my CSS file. I have used anchor tag to add links but I can't remove the text decoration for some reason, I tried internal,external and inline style sheets but nothing is working. This is the footer code below, this footer page has been included in my index.php file using the include() function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type=" text/css">
<!-- My CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/style.css" type=" text/css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>    
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
                <h4>Information</h4>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
                <h4>My Account</h4>                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
                <h4>Contact Us</h4>              
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
                <p><a href="">About Us</a><br>
                   <a href="">Contact Us</a>
                </p>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 content">
                <p><a href="">Login</a><br>
                   <a href="">Signup</a>
                </p>                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
                <p>Contact: +91-9742485069</p>              
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>                                      
</footer>
</body>    
</html>
```

What should I include in my CSS file to remove the text decoration from the links? Forgive me if I my question doesn't make sense to anyone, posting here for the first time.

This question was marked as duplicate but I have tried all the solutions mentioned in another question, [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11419998/7779606) and those solutions didn't work for me.

Comment: I dont see any attempt to remove the decoration on anchor tags?

Comment: That's because I have tried multiple ways to remove the decoration but nothing has worked yet.

Comment: I think the Bootstrap CSS file is overriding the selectors in my CSS file.

Comment: Well put your css file after that of boostraps! Thats what the C in CSS stands for `cascading`

Comment: @RiggsFolly My css is included after the bootstrap css in the code.

Comment: This is an old post but for people finding this, I believe the problem is this: "_Text decorations are drawn across descendant text elements. This means that if an element specifies a text decoration, then a child element can't remove the decoration._" So if an element has a text decoration, a child element cannot remove it by using `text-decoration:none;`

[learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but you want this ? [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sgq2hcan/2/)

```
.footer a { color: #fff; }
.footer a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work :(

Comment: Check about specificity of selectors : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity
Check if there is `!important` value in the browser inspector applied on anchor, it should fix your issue

Comment: I inspected and checked, but there is no !important value applied on the anchor.

Comment: Can you do an exact fiddle of your code, so I can help you more efficiently ?

Comment: Well I wanted to do a fiddle of my code, but I am having another problem now. Bootstrap isn't working for me now, it was working perfectly fine yesterday. I will try to solve that problem first :(

Comment: Here is the fiddle which I created, [My JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/sgq2hcan/1/)

Comment: I've updated my asnwer with your fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sgq2hcan/2/

Comment: Thank you that worked :)     text-decoration: none; removes only the underline?

Comment: yep, it remove all text-decoration properties (underline, line-through, ... )

Comment: It doesn't remove the color of the text?

Comment: The color is changed by `color` property

Comment: I thought the text-decoration: none; removes the color too.

Answer (score 0):

Add text-decoration:none in the hover selector

```css
a:hover{
  text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
                <h4>Information</h4>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
                <h4>My Account</h4>                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
                <h4>Contact Us</h4>              
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
                <p><a href="">About Us</a><br>
                   <a href="">Contact Us</a>
                </p>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 content">
                <p><a href="">Login</a><br>
                   <a href="">Signup</a>
                </p>                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
                <p>Contact: +91-9742485069</p>              
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>                                      
</footer>
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work .