# Remove text decoration when div is linked

Tags: html, css

So I made a div as a box with text. When I then put it in < a href="#" > tag It looks like this:

https://i.gyazo.com/8103b9cc1968842e88afa4c4971b64ea.png

My problem is that I can't remove the line under the text.

My code:

HTML:

```
<div class="sommersalg">

    <div id="prosent">
        50%-75%
    </div>

    <p>SOMMERSALG</p>

    <a href="produkter.html">
        <div id="handle">
            HANDLE NÅ
        </div>
    </a>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.sommersalg a #handle {

    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 7.5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -290px;
    color: #586e72;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #3686a3;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sommersalg #handle:hover {
    top: -289.25px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #3686a3;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Show the complete code, not only part of it...

Comment: update the question, don't add this in a comment.

Comment: The native behaviour is to underline the link, not the `#handle`. Use `.sommersalg a:hover` as a selector instead https://jsfiddle.net/awzh91yv/3/

Comment: Ok, so now it works when I hover on it, but how can I remove the line when I am not hovering on it @baao

Comment: Add `.sommersalg a {
    text-decoration: none;
}`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the `<a>` tag to `text-decoration: none;`. Not the `div` inside.

```css
.sommersalg a #handle {

    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 7.5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -290px;
    color: #586e72;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #3686a3;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sommersalg #handle:hover {
    top: -289.25px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #3686a3;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sommersalg a {
  text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="sommersalg">

    <div id="prosent">
        50%-75%
    </div>

    <p>SOMMERSALG</p>

    <a href="produkter.html">
        <div id="handle">
            HANDLE NÅ
        </div>
    </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all put the text inside of a p tag , then use this code in your CSS file :

```
#handle > p { text-decoration:none;}
```

instead of p tag u also can use span , by then your css should be :

```
#handle > span {text-decoration:none;}
```

just note that p is blocked by nature (means that it takes whole width) but span is not and it just takes what ever it needs from width!

Comment: is it possible to use id or class in p tag? I already have p's in my code..

Comment: Yes you can use both of them

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with div element inside the  element, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419998/text-decoration-none-not-working).
Have you added an html doctype?

The "text-decoration: none;" is all right in .sommersalg a. You do not need to add a :hover part.